# Getting 404 error when loading bootstrap based homepage in Django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-views

I am newbie to django.

The error that i am getting in my terminal is

> "GET static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1676

My working Directory is something like this:

```
*Project
**App
**blog
**static
**db.sqlite3
**manage.py
```

On my Homepage I had tried two things

a) without static tag i.e. **href=  "static/css/bootstrap.min.css"**

b) Using static tag i.e **href={% static "static/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}"

I had even added the

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/HOME/AA/Project/blog/templates ',)
```

How should I fix this GET error and properly render my bootstrap files? I had even added these files as Static.

Here is my settings.py

```
Django settings for luckdrum project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'q^6oh!prd$jt*@sz@#&n(i5$etxv-13-pr+%x9_0y$#7$tnfq('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'luckdrum.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'luckdrum.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/templates/',
               '/home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/blog/accounts/',




)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
TEMPLATE_DEBUG =True
```

Comment: I don't know if the typo is just in your question or if it's also in your code but your terminal error says "static/cs" not "static/cs**s**"

Comment: @BSMP Edited.Thanks for the correction

Comment: Did you configured ``staticfiles`` settings? Did you ran ``collectstatic`` command?

Comment: @v1k45 yeah i did that too.

Comment: @BlackUser what is you STATICFILES set to in settings?

Comment: try adding 
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]` in your settings.py

Comment: @utkbansal I had added your configured file edited one. It's GIving me the following error >"The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

Comment: I add even added my settings.py file in Question

Comment: @BlackUser comment out the static_root for now

Comment: @utkbansal Done. Not working still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97748/discussion-between-black-user-and-utkbansal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all comment out the STATIC_ROOT setting from settings.py

Then add the following line to it -

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

Finally use the tag `{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}`. Notice you don not need 'static' in the quotes.